# Is it possible to disable line anti-aliasing in GNU Octave 4.0.2?

Tags: octave

I have Ubuntu 17 which does not offer Octave 4.2. 
What can I do to disable line anti aliasing in the output of

```
x = [3738.519,  4153.116,  3739.660, 3738.519];
y = [6424.256, 6031.496, 6156.235, 6424.256];
plot(x,y)
```

?

Comment: which graphics_toolkit?

Comment: Octave 4.2 support `set (gcf, "graphicssmoothing", "off")`. I'm unsure if you implicitly want to tell us that you already know that.

Comment: Yes I came to understand that Octave 4.2 supports disabling the smoothing, but I couldn't find a way to do the same with Octave 4.0.2.

About the graphics toolkit... I'm actually running Lubuntu and I have installed Octave from the Zeisty repository. So that's as much as I know about the toolkit.

Comment: You're probably better off installing the latest octave from source anyway. See [here](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Compiling_from_source) for more info. The only thing I would add to that page is that you may want to install to a particular directory instead of the default one for hassle-free tweaking, or multi-versioning etc (I usually go for `./configure --prefix=/opt/octave-4.2`)

Comment: I never used Ubuntu but doesn't this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable) with GNU Octave 4.2.1 work for Ubuntu 17?